# Removing first cell from section with 3 cells in html

Tags: html, grid, shopify, cell, liquid

I have a section on a page on a shopify website that was 3 cells. The goal is to remove the 1st and 2nd cell from the section. I have successfully removed the 2nd cell, but can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong to remove the 1st cell.

I successfully used this code in the theme liquid file to remove the second cell

```
  <style>
#shopify-section-template--19687751713064__main > div > div > section > x-grid > x-cell:nth-child(2) {
    display: none !important;
}
</style>
```

I tried changing to (1) to remove the 1st cell, but unsuccessful. Are there any obvious reasons why this isn't wowrking?

```
  <style>
#shopify-section-template--19687751713064__main > div > div > section > x-grid > x-cell:nth-child(1) {
    display: none !important;
}
</style>
```